# Not authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sam-cli

I need to scan a dynamodb database but I keep getting this error:

> "errorMessage": "An error occurred (AccessDeniedException) when
>   calling the Scan operation: User:
>   arn:aws:sts::747857903140:assumed-role/test_role/TestFunction is not
>   authorized to perform: dynamodb:Scan on resource:
>   arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:747857903140:table/HelpBot"

This is my Lambda code (index.py):

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
table = client.Table('HelpBot')

def handler(event, context):
    table.scan()
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

This is my SAM template (template.yml):

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: 'AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31'
Resources:
  MyFunction:
    Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Runtime: python3.6
      Policies:
        Version: '2012-10-17'
        Statement:
        - Effect: Allow
          Action:
          - dynamodb:Scan
          Resource: arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:747857903140:table/HelpBot
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Does you lambda role have the DynamoDB policies applied?

Go to

1. IAM Go to policies
2. Choose the DynamoDB policy (try full access and then go back and restrict your permissions)
3. From Policy Actions - Select Attach Attach it to the role that is
   used by your Lambda

Comment: Nice. Worked well.

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring the boto client to use your IAM role directly in the lambda function.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_use_switch-role-api.html

```
import json
import boto3

client = boto3.resource(
    'dynamodb',
    aws_access_key_id = ACCESS_KEY,
    aws_secret_access_key = SECERT_KEY
)

table = client.Table('HelpBot')

def handler(event, context):
    table.scan()
    return {
        "statusCode": 200,
        "body": json.dumps('Hello from Lambda!')
    }
```

Comment: NEVER use access keys in code. This solution is very insecure. Use IAM roles instead.

Comment: @AnatoliiDev Good advice, but you need credentials to assume a role.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are not applying the default role (autogenerated) to your lambda, you need to create a rol with lambda basic execution permissions and attach this when you are creating your lambda or in the configuration pane, in the left choose permissions and change it.